# Goutte extract text with tags

Tags: php, web-scraping, goutte, domcrawler

While trying to learn and use Goutte to scrape websites for descriptions, it does retrieve text but removes all tags (i.e. `<br><b>`).
Is there a way to retrieve the values of all text within the div, including html tags?
Or is there an easier alternative way that does give me this ability?

```
    <?php 
            require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
            use Goutte\Client;

            // Init. new client
            $client = new Client();
            $crawler = $client->request('GET', "examplesite.com/example");

            // Crawl response
            $description = $crawler->filter('element.class')->extract('_text');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `html()` frunction

> http://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_html

Like this

```
$descriptions = $crawler->filter('element.class')->each(function($node) {
    return $node->html();
})
```

After you can use `strip_tags` PHP function to clean it up

> http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Had no idea this was a function, solved everything thank you